# How to print values from multiple table in single table row in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySql database, Named Items and Types, In Items I have Chair, table, etc,. In Types I have Wood and Iron.

## Items Table

```
+--------+-----------+
| ItemID | Item_Name |
+--------+-----------+
|    1   | Chair     |
|    2   | Table     |
|    3   | Bed       |
+--------+-----------+
```

## Types Table

```
+--------+-----------+
| TypeID | Item_Type |
+--------+-----------+
|    1   | Iron      |
|    2   | Wood      |
+--------+-----------+
```

Now I want to print this in a php table as follows,

## New Table

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Item Name  | Item Type One | Item Type Two |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Chair      | Iron          | Wood          |
| Table      | Iron          | Wood          |
| Bed        | Iron          | Wood          |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I tried this code:

```
<?php
  $query_Item = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_Items");
  $itemsRowCount = $query_Item->num_rows;

  $query_Type = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_Types");
  $typesRowCount = $query_Type->num_rows;
?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Item Type One</th>
    <th>Item Type Two</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  if($itemsRowCount > 0){
    while($row = $query_Item->fetch_assoc()){
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?></td>
    <?php
    if($typesRowCount > 0){
      while($row = $query_Type->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['ItemType']; ?></td>
    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
  </tr>
    <?php
    }
  }
?>
</table>
```

But its giving output like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| Item Name | Item Type One | Item Type Two |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| Chair     | Iron          | Wood          |
| Table     |               |               |
| Bed       |               |               |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Only Printing the first row as it should be.
What is the problem? How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your data model or expectation needs to be adjusted, because I don't see any clean way or joining the `Items` and `Types` tables to generate the output table you expect.  That being said, you could do a cross join of the two tables, followed by a pivot on the `TypeID` column to generate what you want.

```
SELECT
    t1.Item_Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.TypeID = 1 THEN t2.Item_Type END) AS Item_Type_One,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t2.TypeID = 1 THEN t2.Item_Type END) AS Item_Type_Two
FROM Items t1
INNER JOIN Types t2
GROUP BY
    t1.ItemID,
    t1.Item_Name
```

**Output:**

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Item Name  | Item_Type_One | Item_Type_Two |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Chair      | Iron          | Wood          |
| Table      | Iron          | Wood          |
| Bed        | Iron          | Wood          |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the result set `$query_Type` is exhausted in the first row itself. You have to adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could iterate through it again. Make use of [`mysqli_result::data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to adjust the result pointer.

Do `$query_Type->data_seek(0);` right after the inner `while` loop.

```
// your code
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Item Type One</th>
        <th>Item Type Two</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        if($itemsRowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query_Item->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['ItemName']; ?></td>
            <?php
                if($typesRowCount > 0){
                    while($row = $query_Type->fetch_assoc()){
                ?>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ItemType']; ?></td>
                <?php
                    }
                    $query_Type->data_seek(0);
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```